# Print a Spring variable in browser using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, spring

I am trying to print the variable in the `if` condition. It's done using Spring and JavaScript. I don't know Spring. How do I print the value of a Spring variable in the browser?

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this code in a `.jsp` file, by chance?

Comment: @ajp15243 Yep. JSP EL Expressions.

Comment: Dear @user2378250, what do you mean by ***print the value of a Spring variable in the browser***?? Alert it? Print in the console? Put it in another HTML element?

Comment: What are you trying to print? Which variable needs to be printed?

Comment: Your JSP file is evaluated *server-side*, meaning it is not executing the JavaScript code at all, it's just going through and (in this case) just replacing `${...}` with the string value of that given expression (which all seem to just contain variable names). Whatever values pop out there are what end up being sent as JavaScript to the *client* (the browser), where it is then executed as JS. You should be able to do something like `alert("${myVariable}");`, which gets sent as `alert("some-value");` to the client, and is then executed as an `alert` with the value that the server placed there.

Comment: @acdcjunior: thanks for your reply how to print this variage in alert and console in browser createBehavior.behaviorRevisionAllowed

Comment: @ajp15243: thanks for your reply how can i print it in the console.log...can u tell the syntax

Comment: It should be very similar to the `alert` syntax; wrap the JSP EL variable in a `console.log` call like: `console.log("${myExpression}");`. I would make sure you read up on how the server-side JSP processing and execution differs from client-side HTML/JS execution. Let me know if these two things answered your question, and I can post them as an actual answer.

Comment: @ajp15243: thank u so much i got the answer wat does EL variable mean

Comment: @ajp15243: i have another question too is it possible to print and see spring message in the browser } else {
        return [[$('#strtDate'), "<spring:message code='BH-MS-0070'/>"]];
    }

Comment: @ajp15243 Great advice, and you should add those as an answer (as they are an answer, really).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll be attempting to piece together my comments on your question into an answer, since they seem to have solved it.

What you should first understand is the difference between *server-side* code parsing and execution (a JSP page for you), and *client-side* code parsing and execution (HTML and JavaScript for you).  You can read a brief overview in the top-rated answers to [this programmers.stackexchange.com question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-difference-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming).  Further reading can be found on Wikipedia's articles on [server-side scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting) and [client-side scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting). A key concept to take away from the client-side scripting article about server-side scripts is:

> [Server-side scripts] produce output in a format understandable by web browsers (usually HTML), which is then sent to the user's computer. The user cannot see the script's source code (unless the author publishes the code separately), and may not even be aware that a script was executed. Documents produced by server-side scripts may, in turn, contain client-side scripts.

In terms of your setup, this means that when you request your JSP page via your browser, your browser tells the server that is hosting the JSP page that the browser wants that page. The server then executes the JSP page to produce a document that is purely HTML and JavaScript in nature (perhaps some CSS too, if you wrote it that way) for sending to the browser. *The browser never sees the JSP code*. By the time the server is done parsing and executing the JSP page, all instances of `${someExpression}` (JSP EL statements) and other JSP-specific expressions (such as taglibs, like `<spring:xx>` tags) will be resolved to some client-side equivalent. For basic JSP EL statments (`${...}`), these resolve to some string value.  If you happen to cleverly place that EL statement in some JavaScript in the JSP, such as `console.log("${myVariable}");`, then you are dynamically producing JavaScript code that will depend on the output of the EL statement (in this example, it would resolve to something like `console.log("myVariable-value");`).

Up to this point, the server has just been executing JSP code (and otherwise leaving HTML/JS/CSS already in the page intact).  No JavaScript has been parsed or executed. This final "rendered" page, after the server is done executing JSP stuff, is then sent as purely HTML/JS/CSS to the client browser, which receives it and parses/executes it. At this point, the browser sees something like `console.log("myVariable-value");`, without knowing or caring that your JSP code produced it, and executes that (since you cleverly placed your EL statement to produce valid JS).

This long-winded explanation then means you can do the following:

---

Server-side JSP:

```
alert("${createBehavior.behaviorRevisionAllowed}");
```

Resulting code sent from the server to the client browser:

```
alert("false");
```

Result after code is executed in the browser: An `alert` box pops up with the value `false` in it.

---

Server-side JSP:

```
console.log("${createBehavior.behaviorRevisionAllowed}");
```

Resulting code sent from the server to the client browser:

```
console.log("false");
```

Result after code is executed in the browser: The value `false` is logged to the console.

---

Server-side JSP

```
return [$('#some-id'), "<spring:message code='BH-MS-0070'/>"];
```

Resulting code sent from the server to the client browser:

```
return [$('#some-id'), "some-spring-message-string"];
```

Result after code is executed in the browser: The array in the JavaScript `return` statement is created with the value `"some-spring-message-string"` as the second element.

---

From your question in your comment about an "EL variable", when I said "EL variable" I meant the fact that an EL statement, such as `${someStatement}`, could be a statement as simple as a variable name, such as `${createBehavior.behaviorRevisionAllowed}`. This EL statement will see just a variable name in it, attempt to find that variable and get its value, and then replace `${createBehavior.behaviorRevisionAllowed}` with the actual value.

Let me know if further explanation is needed.

Comment: thanks for your reply...how to print this pring message value in the browser and see <spring:message code='BH-MS-0070'/>

Comment: @user2378250 You can put `<spring:message .../>` tags in where you put `${...}` in a `console.log` or `alert` statement. It works the same way, in that the JSP Spring tag is evaluated first and a value is put into the JavaScript code, and then that rendered JavaScript code is sent to the browser for execution. You can even just put `<spring:message .../>` in your HTML (like `<span> <spring:message .../> </span>`), and its value will just be printed to the final HTML page in the browser.

Comment: thanks for your reply when i put alert for the spring message it shows error

Comment: You're going to need to give more detail than that. It is probably appropriate to open a new question about it, detailing what you wrote and the error you are getting.

Comment: alert("i am spring" +"${<spring:message code='BH-MS-0070'/>}");

Comment: Don't wrap it in `${ }`. Spring tags and EL statements are separate things. You can sometimes use an EL statement in a Spring tag in certain situations, but not the other way around.

Comment: can you give the syntax for it

Comment: Simply remove the `${ }` characters from what you posted a few moments ago: `alert("some string" + "<spring:message code='your-message-code'/>");`.